# replacing link text text for mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

This code creates my back/next links for my Wordpress website.

function.php
    " class="">

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>' . _x( get_next_post()->post_title, 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( get_previous_post()->post_title, 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>'); ?>

...
```

html (output)

```
<div class="navigation">
   <div class="nav-previous"> ... </div> 
   <div class="nav-next"> ... </div> 
</div>
```

This creates a link for both the next and previous post. It outputs the title of the link in the div aswell with 'get_next_post()->post_title'.

When on mobile I want to change what the links say to just 'back' and 'next'

Comment: Is your theme based off bootstrap?

Comment: it has bootstrap installed but not based

Comment: If bootstrap is included, you could use the helper classes - `.show-sm`/`.show-xs`/`.hide-sm`/`.hide.xs` etc. Let me whip up an answer quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your themes running with bootstrap, then you're best to use their [helper classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes) for this sort of thing.

```
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>' . _x( get_next_post()->post_title, '<span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Previous post link</span><span class="hidden-xl hidden-lg hidden-md">Prev</span>', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( get_previous_post()->post_title, '<span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Next post link</span><span class="hidden-xl hidden-lg hidden-md">Next</span>', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>'); ?>
```

Comment: does this put them into columns? (i dont want any extra css conditions applied)

Comment: No, no extra columns being added. All it does is show/hide the `<span>`'s accordingly as the window is resized.

Comment: Doesn't hide or replace anything

Comment: Have you included bootstrap into the theme and what version is it?

Comment: Bootstrap is brought in correctly. I have tested the bootstrap 'hidden' feature on other parts and it works. So it's just the placement in my code that's off i guess

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about css media queries?

One easy way to do this is using css media queries. You can do some like this:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>' . _x( get_next_post()->post_title, '<span class="desktop">Previous post link</span><span class="mobile">back</span>', 'bnNav' ) ); ?>
<?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', _x( get_previous_post()->post_title, '<span class="desktop">Next post link</span><span class="mobile">next</span>', 'bnNav' ). '<span class="fa fa-chevron-up icn"></span>'); ?>
```

...

And in your css, you put some like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) { 
    .mobile {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .desktop {
        display: block !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) { 
    .mobile {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .desktop {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Note: I define `680px` the min width to be considered a mobile. You will have to define this number according to your needs.

Comment: I've thought about this as a solution, I was wondering if there's changes/additions to the code to avoid hidding and showing divs

Comment: Changing that doesn't alterthe link title